# Appropriate theme function for alter specific field for a view

Tags: theming, forms

I have used a view in my drupal.

In this view, I have used an "add to cart button" field.

In my theme, I am searching for a theme function in order to alter this field. 
For example  want to remove css classes from this button and add another attributes to it.

what is the suitable theme_function in order to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

Fences should be the answer of your problem:
https://drupal.org/project/fences

Or you could create a template for this view-field:
https://drupal.org/node/352970